# SocialDNA plugin not working in socialEngine

Tags: zend-framework, facebook-social-plugins, socialengine

I'm using SocialEngine4. SocialDNA plugin is not working in my application. It shows following Error.

When i click on facebook Icon it shows the following javascript error

```
openidconnect_fbe is not defined openidconnect_facebook_login_button_clickable()social...s?c=122 (line 224) anonymous()mootoo...s?c=122 (line 1) [Break On This Error]
```

For remaining social network links it shows the following javascript error

```
openidconnect_relay_url is not defined openidconnect_connect_service(service="live", callback=openidconnect_onNotifyConnectedSocial(service))social...s?c=124 (line 1004) onclick(event=click clientX=483, clientY=79)onclick (line 2) [Break On This Error] ...r_window = openidconnect_newwindow( openidconnect_relay_url + '/login/' + servic... if(parseInt(openidconnect_fbe) == 1) {
```

Can any one help me in this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please add Facebook app id in `control panel>plugin>socialdna`